# References problem

Tags: bibtex

I am writing my references using jabref and i created a new database called "ref.bib" but it doesn't work and give errors, any help please?

Here is my database code:

```
% This file was created with JabRef 2.8.1.
% Encoding: MacRoman

@ARTICLE{Yang2011,
  author = {Yang, Chenhui and Olson, Byron and Si, Jennie},
  title = {A multiscale correlation of wavelet coefficients approach to spike
    detection},
  journal = {Neural Comput.},
  year = {2011},
  volume = {23},
  pages = {215--250},
  number = {1},
  month = jan,
  acmid = {1943013},
  address = {Cambridge, MA, USA},
  doi = {10.1162/NECO_a_00063},
  issn = {0899-7667},
  issue_date = {January 2011},
  numpages = {36},
  publisher = {MIT Press},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1162/NECO_a_00063}
}

@comment{jabref-meta: selector_review:}

@comment{jabref-meta: selector_publisher:}

@comment{jabref-meta: selector_author:}

@comment{jabref-meta: selector_journal:}

@comment{jabref-meta: selector_keywords:}
```

Here is a sample of my paper code:

```
\begin{document}
    \IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\section{Introduction}
my introduction \cite{Yang2011}

\bibliography{ref}

Thanks A lot,
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: It Gave me these errors:
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2012)
The top-level auxiliary file: IEEESMC2012.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file IEEESMC2012.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file IEEESMC2012.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file IEEESMC2012.aux
(There were 3 error messages)

Comment: Could you please modify your MWE so it includes the `\begin{document}` part?

Comment: it's already there, i just send a sample of the code

Comment: @sherifHaggag Did you run LaTeX then BibTeX then LaTeX twice?

Comment: i created the database using bibtex then i run the latex using ctrl+shift+B, what do u mean by run bibtex?

Comment: as Joseph mentioned, you need to re-run your file a couple of times so BibTeX gets all the references right.  Have you tried this?

Comment: I run using ctl+t but it doesn't show the ref (it is shown as [?]) and when i use ctrl+shift+B it gave me the same error

Comment: let's try something different. Could you please remove the `@` from the `@comments` in your .bib file?  Just keep the entry of the example and run the file a couple of times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. You have to run (ctrl+t) **both** (bib.ref and test.tex) scripts multiple times. In my case [?] disappears and the right citation is included.

Comment: This of course depends on the frontend to LaTeX you're using; the ones I use don't do anything with CTRL-T, for instance. Can you add which one you're referring to?

Comment: I am using TeXworks